# Office365 Calendar Api - List events from Room

Tags: outlook-restapi

I want to list all meetings reserved in Room in Office365 Calendar. 
I tried with `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{user mail address}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}` but it returns error 401 Unauthorized. 
And I tried with `https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events` but it only returns events from that instance of Calendar. 
Does any of you have experience with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long researches and many spent hours I found that using Exchange Web Services is best solution.

More about it on [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide)